# What acoustic instruments are great for Droning?

Tags: voice, instruments, tone, pitch, sustain

I want a drone, using only acoustic instruments, with as little effort as possible, to accompany singing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is just asking for a list, making every answer essentially of equal value.

Comment: Also see https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic on the inadvisability of list questions and questions seeking recommendations.

Comment: @phoog is there a stack exchange for instrument design info or something of the like?

Comment: Why does playing untouched matter?  That has nothing to do with drone.

Comment: @DataProcessing Interested in using it for singing only. So the least amount of “playing” possible.

Comment: This can easily be edited into a non-list question just by focusing on your need. “I want a drone, using only acoustic instruments, with as little effort as possible.” Spoiler alert, pretty sure it’s a sruti box.

Comment: @AndyBonner I don’t know why, but I originally thought they were all electronic. I’m gonna look into them now. And wouldn’t it still be a question asking for recommendations or a “list” of some sort? That’s why I’m confused about where to have a question/discussion like this.

Comment: “Here’s my problem, what’s the best approach” can have multiple valid answers, but the answers tend to be substantive. One of the problems with “list questions“ is that their answers are often very superficial, like “what are all the pieces Chopin wrote in C major“

Comment: Also, any answers are not likely to be useful to anyone else, since no one but OP knows the parameters of acceptance for their case.

Comment: For more of the rationale behind the policy, see [this meta post](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/162/78419). See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective) about the notion that there can be good questions that still provoke differing valid answers. Your need might be a bit niche but it's totally possible that it help someone with the same need in the future.

Comment: Btw, you might explain why electronics are off-limits. You could easily do a lot just by putting an acoustic signal through a delay effect, or using an E-Bow. The current edit might be a bit *too* minimalist; e.g. does "as little effort as possible" is about making low demands on the performer during the performance, but could be mistaken for "the readiest available solution." You might also spell out that this is for a singer to self-accompany; thus e.g. most mouth-blown wind instruments are out.

Comment: One can play drone on any instrument capable of playing pitched notes. Which one is "great" for that purpose is opinion based. The question about "the least amount of effort" is subjective as well. The suggestion to list "personal favorites" is clearly off-topic.

Comment: "Interested in using it for singing only." Do you mean you want to sing while playing the instrument? This would make bagpipes, listed in both present answers, not a great choice.

Comment: @user1079505 It’s ok, I understand what I did wrong, I’ll just have to speculate for myself. Although, Andy Bonner answered for me before this post will get closed. It was something I did not realize before. Thanks.

Comment: @Lecifer Ask in [The Practice Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room). That's the perfect place for this kind of discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Trivially every wind instrument with a reservoir, like bagpipes, harmoniums, organs.  When the player's mouth cavity is the reservoir, this is called "circular breathing" and can be used for wind instruments with little air use.  The didgeridoo is regularly played in that manner, but circular breathing is also an advanced technique in some demand at professional level for instruments such as oboe and flute.

Then there are instruments with a continuous tone even if not of indeterminate length, like bowed strings.  The hurdygurdy even gives arbitrary-length notes by employing a circular bow and a crank.

Then there are instruments that are kept vibrating mechanically continuously, like singing glasses or even the glass harmonica, or percussion instruments played with soft mallets in a roll, like cymbals or timpani.  There are even plucked string instruments commonly played in a semicontinuous technique like mandolins and balalaikas.

Instrument sections with limited tone length can deliver drones by unsynchronizing breaks in their tone.

Answer (score 1):

Organ, bagpipe, wind gong/tamtam, bells (including church bells as well as plate and tubular bells), Hurdy-Gurdy

The pipe organ is obviously *the* acoustic drone instrument, as with a single keypress it can sound for ever. And even when the key is released the sound will continue, thanks to the long reverb in churches